# Logging Ipywidgets interactions in VS code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

Trying to figure out how I can access to **Jupyter Notebook logging in VS code**, as able to do in **Jupyter lab**.

I have a Jupyter Notebook in my local branch, which runs an app project following MVP pattern. Would like to debug/log **ipywidgets** interactions errors and exceptions in VS code. In Jupyter Lab this it is possible to access to log however don't know how to **access to logs in VS code**.